# Android SDk can't download with failed to fetch URL

Tags: android

I download android sdk,when i first open it,I can install sdk 21.

But now it not work and some error:

***Failed to fetch URL link:  dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, reason: SSLPeerUnverified peer not authenticated***

But when I use chrome **I can fetch**       link  :dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml.

I have set the "force https://...to be fetched using http://..",and i use **Goagent** to install.

Answer (score 0):

Try tools->options->Force https://...source...